# Is $PP^{(PP^A)} = PP^A$ ?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, oracles

I've looked in the [Zoo](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aP#pp) and it seems it is not true because $PH \subseteq P^{PP}$. Nonetheless I've passed by a paper that appears to have used a positive result. It was in the context that $f : \{0,1\}^* \mapsto \{0,1\}^*$ is a function, computable by probabilistic polynomial time oracle machine $M$ with access to an arbitrary oracle $A$. The authors say and I quote:

> Its also immediate that $G^f$ ≡
>   $G^{M^A}$ is computable by a
>   probabilistic polynomial time oracle
>   machine with access to $A$.

where $G$ is a probabilistic polynomial time oracle machine.

They do it again also for $S^{N^A,M^A}$, $S,N$ being other probabilistic polynomial time oracle machine.

Update: the paper is "[Notions of reducibility between cryptographic primitives](http://springerlink.com/content/q3jp67gnpkhkn38q)" - 2004. It was in the proof of Lemma 1 of the part that "If there exists a fully-black-box reduction from a cryptographic primitive P to cryptographic primitive Q then there exists a relativizing reduction from P to Q as well." The definitions of fully-black-box and relativizing reduction is in the paper.

The question now, according to Lance Fortnow's answer that they are not equal, does that mean that this is a gap in the proof ?

Comment: It might help if you tell us which paper you're quoting.

Comment: @Robin Kothari: It is "Notions of reducibility between cryptographic primitives" - 2004 (http://www.springerlink.com/content/q3jp67gnpkhkn38q/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Richard Beigel [gives an oracle](http://www.springerlink.com/content/u57567564x383634/) $A$ where $P^{NP^A}\not\subseteq PP^A$ which immediately gives $PP^{PP^A}\neq PP^A$.

Answer (score 2):

The question appears to be related to the question of whether there exists an oracle relative to which the counting hierarchy [CH](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aC#ch) is infinite or not. This is an open problem according to the Zoo.

Comment: PP and PP^PP are only the first two levels of the hierarchy. It's not clear that an oracle that separates these two would also show that the entire hierarchy is infinite.

Comment: Do you have any idea whether PP^(PP^A) is the same as (PP^PP)^A ?